# Calculating the eigenvalues of this matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I have the following matrix asociated to a $f:R⁴\rightarrow R⁴$ endomorphism:

$\left( \begin{array}{cccc}
1 & b & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & a & 1 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & -a \end{array} \right) $

I calculate the characteristic polynomial and come with this:

$(1-\lambda)*[(1-\lambda)*(a-\lambda)*(-a-\lambda)+(1-\lambda)]$

I would like to know if this is correctly calculated and how the eigenvalues would be calculated from this characteristic polynomial. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks right. As you know, the eigenvalues are the values of $\lambda$ where the polynomial is $0$ (i.e., the roots). Now, in general, if the polynomial were of the form
$$(\lambda-x_1)(\lambda-x_2)(\lambda-x_3)(\lambda-x_4),$$
you would be in luck since in that case, the roots are exactly $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$. So, this is not quite the case for yours, but you can rewrite it as
$$(1-\lambda)(1-\lambda)((a-\lambda)(-a-\lambda)+1)$$
by factoring out $(1-\lambda)$. Expanding the big parenthesis, this is also
$$(1-\lambda)(1-\lambda)(\lambda^2-a^2+1).$$
From this you can see that two of the eigenvalues are $1$, and the remaining two you can find by solving the quadratic equation $\lambda^2-a^2+1=0$ for $\lambda$.